# Need a quick bash script

Tags: bash, move, directory

I have about 100 directories all in the same parent directory that adhere to the naming convention [sitename].com. I want to rename them all [sitename].subdomain.com.

Here's what I tried:

```
for FILE in `ls | sed 's/.com//' | xargs`;mv $FILE.com $FILE.subdomain.com;
```

But it fails miserably. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bash:

```
for i in *
do
    mv $i ${i%%.com}.subdomain.com
done
```

The ${i%%.com} construct returns the value of i without the '.com' suffix.

Answer (score 7):

Use [rename(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename).

```
rename .com .subdomain.com *.com
```

And if you have a [perl rename](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rename) instead of the normal one, this works:

```
rename s/\\.com$/.subdomain.com/ *.com
```

Comment: I think there's an extra period at the end of `.com.`.

Comment: I usually reach for mmv to solve that problem.  Thanks for making me aware of another tool for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.com' -type d -maxdepth 1 \
| while read site; do
    mv "${site}" "${site%.com}.subdomain.com"
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
ls |
grep -Fv '.subdomain.com' |
while read FILE; do
  f=`basename "$FILE" .com`
  mv $f.com $f.subdomain.com
done
```

Answer (score 0):

See: http://blog.ivandemarino.me/2010/09/30/Rename-Subdirectories-in-a-Tree-the-Bash-way

```
#!/bin/bash
# Simple Bash script to recursively rename Subdirectories in a Tree.
# Author: Ivan De Marino <ivan.demarino@betfair.com>
#
# Usage:
#    rename_subdirs.sh <starting directory> <new dir name> <old dir name>

usage () {
   echo "Simple Bash script to recursively rename Subdirectories in a Tree."
   echo "Author: Ivan De Marino <ivan.demarino@betfair.com>"
   echo
   echo "Usage:"
   echo "   rename_subdirs.sh <starting directory> <old dir name> <new dir name>"

   exit 1
}

[ "$#" -eq 3 ] || usage

recursive()
{
   cd "$1"
   for dir in *
   do
      if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
         echo "Directory found: '$dir'"
         ( recursive "$dir" "$2" "$3" )
         if [ "$dir" == "$2" ]; then
            echo "Renaming '$2' in '$3'"
            mv "$2" "$3"
         fi;
      fi;
   done
}

recursive "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for FILE in `ls -d *.com`; do
  FNAME=`echo $FILE | sed 's/\.com//'`;
  `mv $FILE $FNAME.subdomain.com`;
done
```

Comment: -1 for parsing output of `ls` and executing `mv` in an unnecessary subshell.